# Serialize generated class from LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How do i automatically serialize classes that are generated by the mapping of LINQ to SQL? I need to use these objects in WCF.

.NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the designer surface, click on the background (i.e. not on any specific entity), and change the "Serialization Mode" to "Unidirectional". That should add the necessary `[DataContract]` / `[DataMember]` attributes to the whole model, enabling WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Short of using the [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) to generate the classes and compile them, this is impossible. Create DTO's for the transfer. This will make your types strong and whoever is maintaining this code will thank you.

Comment: could you explain DTO's please?

Comment: DTO stands for Data Transfer Object. It basically means creating simple lightweight classes(no business logic) just to transfer the data.